# How to center map to selected point

Tags: arcgis

I have a featurelayer that consists of points. by clicking some row on the table grid, the map view is switched and only one selected point is displayed
by the JavaScript command:

> featureLayer.setDefinitionExpression("ID="+num);

Now my goal is to center the map to this point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you must get the graphic from featureLayer by `featureLayer.graphics`. Then use `map.centerAndZoom(mapPoint, levelOrFactor)` or `map.centerAt(mapPoint)` to zoom to your graphic.

```
var graphic = featureLayer.graphics[0];
if (graphic && graphic.geometry.type === "point") {
    map.centerAndZoom(graphic.geometry, 17); // or map.centerAt(graphic.geometry);
}
```

Comment: thanks! this shifts the map and point is appeared now, but for sure it is not in the center.

Comment: It should be at the center of the map. Can you check that the map domNode is show with its full size.

Comment: New problem: when the featureLayer has more than one point and I apply featureLayer.setDefinitionExpression("ID="+num), the point is filtered ok, but featureLayer.graphics[0] now is set to undefined and I am unable to center the map

Comment: Because it didn't have the point that matched your definition (or matched but it didn't in the current extent. see how the FeatureLayer working).